# search algorithm in SPARQL?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph, rdf, sparql

I have two questions regarding the SPARQL in fetching data from RDF.

1. What underlying search algorithm does SPARQL uses to fetch the data?
2. How do i use the different search algorithm to fetch data from RDF?

Answer (score 2):

There is no standard answer to 1, that's going to differ from database to database.  Generally though, it's not a search algorithm how I think you mean it.  Most databases are going to take the query algebra resulting from the parsing of the SPARQL query and turn it into a series of scans, joins, filters, etc. that will get the answers for the query out of the index.  It's a process that is not entirely dis-similar from relational query answering.

For 2, I don't have the slightest idea what you're talking about.  You fetch RDF data from a triple store either from the triple store's API, or via SPARQL.  That's about it.  You can build your own algorithm on top of these two mechanisms for accessing the data, and then you're free to use what ever algorithm you like, but you're not going to be able to alter any of the underlying bits of the triple store you're using.

Comment: I will add that if you're using a Sesame-based triple store, you can use the Tinkerpop Blueprints stuff to overlay Gremlin the graph query language on your Sesame repository to allow you to use Gremlin as the query language.  This will not be nearly as efficient as SPARQL (at least the last time I check w/ their implementation) because they're not translating Gremlin into the internal query operators of the triple store, the are merely implementing it against the Sesame API.  It's a handy approach if you like Gremlin, but I'm not sure how well it scales.